# escape backslashes in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a string array in properties file, and I want to read its value in `dataweave` in JSON format.

The array in properties file is-

```
Countries = ["USA","England","Australia"]
```

in `dataweave`, I am using this-

```
%output application/json

---
{
countries: p('Countries')
}
```

Output I am getting is-

```
"countries": "[\"USA\",\"England\",\"Australia\"]",
```

Output I want is-

```
"countries": [
    "USA",
    "England",
    "Australia"
  ]
```

I have tried with `replace` but no luck.

I also tried `countries map $ as String` after changing country array to `Countries = ['USA','England','Australia']` but it says `Invalid input 'S', expected :type or enclosedExpr`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that properties file values are strings and not arrays so your expression is not interpreted. But don't worry you can use the read function 
   read(p('Countries'), "application/json"))